# Alternative to fast user switch applet in Ubuntu Lucid

Tags: ubuntu, user-accounts, users, ubuntu-10.04

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu Jaunty to Lucid and one thing that is missing is the fast user switch applet. This is confirmed by [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fast-user-switch-applet/+bug/563922), for example.

The fast user switch applet was good, because it listed the users in a menu accessible with one click. Now I have to click "switch user", wait for GDM to appear and then choose the user.

Is there an alternative to the fast user switch applet, that works in Lucid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it myself now. It was there all along in the "Indicator Applet Session" applet. I didn't realize it, because this applet is divided into one part displaying my user name and one part displaying a power button that looks exactly like the "Shut Down" applet. I assumed that the user list should be in the user name part, but it was in the power button part (which I didn't try before since I assumed it would be the same as the shutdown applet).

In short: problem solved!